# How to prove $1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \frac15 + \cdots + \frac1n = \frac km$ using induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I was trying to prove this. I tried somehow but didn't get any idea. I think we can prove this using induction. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me.

$$1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \frac15 + \cdots + \frac1n = \frac km$$

where $n>1$, $k$ is odd and $m$ is an even integer.

Comment: $$k/m+1/(n+1)=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee do you mean the induction hypothesis? 
That's all the question said. I think it doesn't matter what 'k' or 'm' is. The thing that matters is we can show that the RHS of this equation can be an odd integer on an even one!

Comment: @Rasoolll yes your interpretation is correct. see below answer.

Comment: You asked how to prove with induction, I think @lab-bhattacharjee was telling you what you needed to investigate in order to do it.  The denominator of that fraction sum is even (since $m$ is even) and the top is the same parity as $n+1$ (since it's $(n+1)k + m$ and $m$ is even and $k$ is odd.  So that's easy when $n+1$ is odd because it's straightforwardly an odd over an even.  I haven't worked past this point; what remains to be done, if this approach is to bear fruit, is to address the case where $n+1$ is even.

Comment: Instead of induction on $n$, what about induction on $k$ where $k$ is the largest nonnegative integer such that $2^k \leq n$?